# Linux Kernel Programming for Beginners

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I have been working on LINUX for the past six years, and am a core Linux
guys since I started my career on Linux. Working more on Redhat /
Centos / Fedora based distribution system administration, with some
basic bash scripting knowledge.

Now I am looking to deep dive into programming to contribute or
innovate something new on Linux operating system or kernel space.
(More importantly on kvm virtualization front since I am an expert on
virtualization).  So I need your guidance to start my new career on
Linux programming front. As of now, I am planning to start with below
sequences:

- C
- C++
- Linux kernel Programming
- Python
- Java

Kindly provide me some good web links or beginner to advanced docs for the above languages to start with.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't know programming, the kernel is very far out of reach for you at this time. Learn C. Try [The C Programming Language](http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1282564716&sr=1-1) first, perhaps followed by the excellent [Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201433079/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1282565172&sr=1-1).

And then you're ready to start looking at kernel source code and looking at kernel-specific books. Depending on what you want to do, it's probably a good idea to pick up some assembly as well.

C++ and Java are pretty well useless for *Linux* kernel development (this is *not* a judgement on either language, it's just that Linux is written in C and assembly).

Comment: Not trying to get it _off topic_, but I'd really appreciate it if you would also name some of those "kernel-specific" books.

Answer (score 9):

[Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) and [Kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/) are both good places to start.

Answer (score 7):

I've read somewhere that Robert Love's book on kernel programming is pretty good for what you are trying to accomplish. [Here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468) the link on AMAZON.

Answer (score 7):

You can start with [Eudyptula Challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/).

The eudyptula-challenge site says: The Eudyptula Challenge is a series of programming exercises for the Linux kernel,that start from a very basic "Hello world" kernel module, moving on up in complexity to getting patches accepted into the main Linux kernel source tree.

You can also go through [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html). It is also a good guide for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not a kernel developer, I think [this](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/#blkd) may help you. It contains a list of kernel related documents.